# How do I generate a report of all changes to multiple files by a particular CVS user?

Tags: cvs

I'm working with a CVS repository where a developer made multiple changes to multiple files after a specific version.  Other contributor also made changes to the files.

Is there a way to generate a report of the files (enhancement to the request: and line changes) made by a specific contributor to CVS after a specific time period?

Comment: Try `cvs blame` (or maybe it's `cvs annotate`).